# How to break out of a loop and not execute the other statements in that loop?

Tags: c, loops, break

```
void process(){
  int ID;
  float hours_employee_worked, hourly_wages_for_employees;
  float tax = 0.4;
  float overtime = 1.5;
  float time_without_overtime, total_overtime;
  float total, average;


  do {
    printf("Enter Employee ID (or -1 to exit): ");
    scanf("%d", &ID);
    printf("Enter hours worked (e.g 8.5 hours): ");
    scanf("%f", &hours_worked);
    printf("Enter hourly wage (e.g 20.25): ");
    scanf("%f", &hourly_wage);
    if (ID == -1)
    {
      puts("All done");
      break;
    }
    else if (hours_employee_worked <=40)
    {
      total = hours_employee_worked* hourly_wages_for_employees;
      average = total * tax;
      average = total - average;
      printf("%.2f", average);
    }
    else if (hours_employee_worked > 40)
    {
      total_overtime = ((hours_employee_worked- 40) * 1.5) * hourly_wage_for_employees;
      total = (40 * hourly_wages_for_employees+ total_overtime) * tax;
      time_without_overtime = 40 * hourly_wages_for_employees;
      average = time_without_overtime + total_overtime - total;
      printf("%f", average);
    }

  }while (ID != -1);

}
```

Basically, I want my program to end execution if the employee ID is equal to -1. But it still continues and breaks at the end. It doesnt say "All done" till the execution is finished and doesn't break out of the loop. Thanks.

Comment: nvm figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works fine if you want you can move your first if statement to the top of your program right after you check employee_id.